# Find matched pairs and their ids for matching records

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyr

I have a huge dataset from where I need to matched samples based on some criteria. For example, for every movie star in a location and borough find me two people (random) who are not movie stars. It is 1 for movie star and 0 for non-movie star.

```
location<- c('manhattan', 'manhattan' ,'manhattan', 'manhattan', 'manhattan', 'manhattan')
moviestar<- c(0,1,0,0,0,1)
id<- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
 borough <- c('williamsburg', 'williamsburg', 'williamsburg', 'williamsburg', 'williamsburg','williamsburg')

 df<- data.frame(location,moviestar, borough, id)
```

I want to create a subset which has matched pairs of movie star with two other non-movie stars (randomly picked) living in the same location and borough. Any advise?Essentially there are 6 people living in manhattan and there are two stars living in manhattan and I want to match for each star, in this case, 2 and 6 are stars, then I would like to have matched pairs in the final data as follows (some random pairs):

The output I am expecting is like this,

```
    matcheddata
    location moviestar borough       id matchpairid
    manhattan    1    williamsburg   2  match1
    manhattan    0    williamsburg   1  match1
    manhttan     0    williamsburg   5  match1
    manhattan    1    williamsburg   6  match2
    manhattan    0    williamsburg   3  match2
    manhttan     0    williamsburg   5  match2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another approach to directly produce the expected result where each row of a movie star is followed by two rows of randomly picked non-movie stars:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, {
  n_stars <- .SD[moviestar == 1, .N]
  rbind(.SD[moviestar == 1], .SD[moviestar == 0][sample.int(.N, 2L * n_stars)])[
    , pairid := rep(1:n_stars, 3L)][order(pairid)]
}, by = .(location, borough)]
```

> ```
>     location      borough moviestar id pairid
> 1: manhattan williamsburg         1  2      1
> 2: manhattan williamsburg         0  3      1
> 3: manhattan williamsburg         0  1      1
> 4: manhattan williamsburg         1  6      2
> 5: manhattan williamsburg         0  4      2
> 6: manhattan williamsburg         0  5      2
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(moviestar.id = id[moviestar == 1],
              match.id = sample(id[moviestar == 0], 2*sum(moviestar == 1)))
          , by = .(location, borough)]
#    location      borough moviestar.id match.id
#1: manhattan williamsburg            2        3
#2: manhattan williamsburg            6        5
#3: manhattan williamsburg            2        1
#4: manhattan williamsburg            6        4
```

You can massage it to whatever form you like afterwards.

Comment: I am not getting the output as expected, for every star, i want to have two non stars, it is only giving me 4 rows after the iteration, and I couldn't get the match pair the star with id 2, any thoughts? thanks you :)

Comment: I've added the output above so you can comment more explicitly how that's not what you asked for. As you can see above, for each star, there are 2 matched non-stars.

Comment: 2 is a star and I need find two matched pairs who are non-stars (like records 1, 3,5) and two for the star with id 6. but in your case I don't see any non-movie stars. please see the output that I have in my question.thanks so much!!

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Star 2 above is matched with non-stars 1 and 3; while star 6 is matched with non-stars 4 and 5. Are you saying you want to match 4 people to each star? In that case multiply by 4 instead of 2, and do a sample with replacement (since you only have 4 people to choose from in the example).

Comment: I think i know what you did here. thats  neat! I guess i need to merge it with the original for the matched pairs to replicate my result. Is there a way can i get the self-match i.e., the star 2 matching star 2 as well to get my result?

Comment: Smth like this: `df[above_result[, .(list(match.id)), by = moviestar.id], on = .(id = moviestar.id), pair := V1]`. Adjust to match your needs.